# Char seperated by a decimal into a double c++

Tags: c++

I am passing a string variable (std::string) and iterating through the string character by character. Whenever I run into a decimal, I want to combine the previous position on the string (i.e 2) and the next position in the string (i.e 5) into a double. So how would I go about making the char 2, char . , char 5 into one whole value (2.5)?

```
std::double x;
std::string varibleName = "4 5 7 2.5";
       for (int i = 0; i < variableName.length(); i++) // iterates through variableName
       {
          if (variableName[i] == '.'){ // if the current position of the iteration is a decimal, I want to grab the char before the decimal and the char after the decimal so I can combine all three positions of the string making it 2.5 and not 25.
           }
       }
```

Comment: Eh, `std::strtod`?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Start by posting a [mcve] illustrating your problem. Then *maybe* we'll have a chance to answer. Bad question; downvoted.

Comment: I tried `std::strtod` didn't get any luck. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49417153/edit) what you tried.

Comment: It doesn't mean it doesn't fit for your purpose. Show us your attempt and how it didn't work.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687269/confused-how-to-convert-from-a-string-to-double-using-strtod-in-c

Comment: [std::stof, std::stod, std::stold](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are wildly overthinking it. The C++ library provides [std::stof, std::stod, std::stold](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) that does exactly what you want. Convert a string like `"2.5"` to a `float`, `double` or `long double`, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {

    std::string s = "2.5";
    double d = std::stod(s);

    std::cout << d << "\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stodex
2.5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further overthinking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that giving an example, code snips, and error logs make troubleshooting a lot easier :)

It sound like you have some input like `"2.1"` and need to convert it to a double like `2.1`?

If that is the case you can use the [`<cstdlib>` `atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) function.

Example:

```
/* atof example: sine calculator */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, fgets */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atof */
#include <math.h>       /* sin */

int main ()
{
  double n;
  char buffer[256];
  printf ("Enter degrees: ");
  fgets (buffer,256,stdin);
  n = atof (buffer);
  printf ("You entered %s which is a double like %f\n" , buffer, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the right language, but the sentiment is the same. Don't use `atof` in C. It has zero error checking. Instead use `strtod` which properly sets `errno` on failed conversion as well as providing an `endptr` parameter to validate whether a conversion took place.

Comment: Please don't use C code on a C++ answer.